# Windows restarting certain applications after a Windows Update

Tags: windows, windows-update, reboot

So I've come across this strange function in Windows where after a Windows Update and the reboot it tries to restore your session prior to restarting.

This though only works with Microsoft's own applications, namely Internet Explorer, Windows Explorer and Visual Studio. I didn't see it yet happening with other applications (I'll have to see with Office). Internet Explorer restores all tabs that were present before the forced Windows Update shutdown and Explorer opens all the folders again (like back in Windows 98 where it did this on every restart)

My question is: How did Windows Update implement this? How can other programs salvage this functionality too?

Comment: IIRC, these are built into the applications on a per-application basis.

Comment: Hmm, sure of that?

Comment: Hold on, do you mean the application restores your session when *you* manually start it, or the application is started *automatically* and your session is restored?

Comment: Automatically after for example a Windows Update is applied. Windows tries to sneak that by you if you leave your computer for a while. It automatically restarts your computer and attempts to restore the session how it was before. It did the restarting. Not all programs work with this mechanic though. So some will restart exactly the way they were and some will not restart at all.

Answer (score 0):

## Windows 10

Starting in Windows 10 update 2004, Microsoft [added an option](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/what-s-new-for-it-pros-in-windows-10-version-2004/ba-p/1419764) to re-open restartable apps at login.

It's configurable in `Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options`.

[image]

## Windows 8.1 and Older

What you've encountered is most likely a new feature of Windows 10 that re-opens restartable apps after the restart so that you can continue where you left off. It was not possible to configure this before Windows 10 version 2004. Below are some methods to attempt to mimic this on older versions of Windows.

---

There is a way to have explorer restore its windows when you restart your computer. This is a built-in option that can be found in Control Panel -> Folder Options. It is in the `View` tab and is called **Restore previous folder windows on logon**.

[image: restore previous folder windows picture]

---

A possible method Windows Update may have used is populating the Logged in User(s) RunOnce registry keys with programs to start. If you are familiar with editing the Windows registry, the key is:
`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce]`
Just as the Run key, this key takes values of REG_SZ (String Value) with the name of the value being the description, and the data of the value being the absolute path to the program you want to start.

This key is read on logon and Windows runs the programs specified there, discarding the entries thereafter.

---

There are third party solutions discoverable by searching "restore windows session".

[Cache My Work](https://cachemywork.codeplex.com/) is an example. It has been reviewed by [addictive tips](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/save-and-restore-desktop-session-in-windows-7-with-cache-my-work/).

Comment: Can you expand upon how that program works?

Comment: I never used it, has this edit cleared that up?